# Regex to match specific URL fragment and not all other URL possibilities

Tags: javascript, regex, url, url-fragment

I have - let say - example.com website and there I have `account` page.
It may have GET parameters, which is also considered part of account page.
It also may have URL fragment. If it's `home.html` fragment - it is still the account page. And if another fragment - then it's a different sub-page of the account page.

So - I need a RegEx (JS) to match this case. This is what I managed to build so far:

```
example.com\/account\/(|.*\#home\.html|(\?(?!.*#.*)))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/ihjCIg/1

The first 4 are the cases I need. And as you see - the second row is not matched by my RegEx.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You may be interested in the `window.location` object where you can check `pathname` and `hash` without worrying about the parameters. However, the parameters are available in `search` if you need them.

Comment: Do you want to exclude the last two cases?

Comment: This is happening in a 3rd party tool, otherwise I would make it just check the pathname and the hash and will handle all the cases I want :)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this [`Regex`](https://regex101.com/r/ihjCIg/1)

Answer (score 3):

You could create 2 optional groups, 1 to optionally match `?` and matching any char except `#` and another optional group matching `#home.html`

Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
^example\.com\/account\/(?:\?[^#\r\n]*)?(?:#home\.html)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `example\.com\/account\/` Match start
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\?[^#\r\n]*` Match `?` and 0+ times any char except `#` or a newline
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `#home\.html` Match `#home.html`
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FDIISD/1)

```js
let pattern = /^example\.com\/account\/(?:\?[^#\r\n]*)?(?:#home\.html)?$/;
[
  "example.com/account/",
  "example.com/account/?brand=mine",
  "example.com/account/#home.html",
  "example.com/account/?brand=mine#home.html",
  "example.com/account/#other.html",
  "example.com/account/?brand=mine#other.html"
].forEach(url => console.log(url + " --> " + pattern.test(url)));
```

Comment: Not pretty sure `xyz.com/?#123` is valid url schema or not, if not than we probably need to have `*` quantifier replaced with `+` and also consider having something like `queryName=queryValue` structure, anyways +1

Comment: @CodeManiac I get your point. In this case it is for a broad match only and it could potentially match more questionable url formats. In that case I think a specific set of allowed characters by the OP would be better.

Comment: Yeah totally agree with you, regex can handle only the specified one's only, to be more generic we should always prefer the URL api :)

Answer (score 1):

Third alternative in your group has a negative look ahead which ensures it rejects any text that contains a `#` but you haven't specifically mentioned anything that should match rest of the content till end of line. Check this updated regex demo,

https://regex101.com/r/ihjCIg/3

If you notice, I have escaped your first dot just before `com` and have added `.*` after the negative look ahead part so it matches your second sample.

Comment: But I have `.*` right after the `#` ... I thought this is handling the rest characters, til the end of the URL ...

Comment: @peshohristov: Ok, that `.*` after `#` was just needed to be taken out of negative lookahead and it would work like you expected. Check this updated link https://regex101.com/r/ihjCIg/6

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

```regex
example\.com\/account\/((\??[^#\r\n]+)?(#?home\.html)?)?$
```

This matches your first four strings

```
example.com/account/
example.com/account/?brand=mine
example.com/account/#home.html
example.com/account/?brand=mine#home.html
```

and excludes your last two

```
example.com/account/#other.html
example.com/account/?brand=mine#other.html
```